# Paypal PayLater not showing in frontend

Tags: paypal-express, magento2.4.3, paypal-paylater

Never worked with Paypal PayLater before but on a Magento 2.4.3 build, we've got it enabled and set to display in frontend but nothing appears at all in frontend...

Our client has completed the sign-up on Paypal's website but of course, we've got no idea what's actually involved with that and if they have done this properly.

Does anyone here set up Paypal PayLater? Is something else required other than enabling it in the backend?

Have reverted to the default theme and also the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in Magento 2.4.3 that prevents Paypal Pay Later from displaying.
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/33883#issuecomment-903383595

Should be fixed in the update coming out tomorrow 10-12-21.

Comment: This seems to be an issue related to viewing orders, invoices etc in backend when PayLater is used due to it missing the <title> in the config. I'm struggling with just getting it to display the logo and description of PayLater in the frontend when enabled from the backend. I have since got it showing in the header as per config backend but I wanted to display it by the add to basket and Paypal buttons.